# Division with $4k+3$ numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why can't a prime number of the form $4k+3$ divide $a^2+1$ for some $a$?
Does when i change the word prime number into not prime number this remains true? 
Same  why can't $p|a^2+6^2$ where $p=4k+3$ if it doesn't divide them both?
I mean i know $a^2+1$ can give $2$ or $1 \mod 4$ but that doesn't mean $4k+3 $cant divide him.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be a prime of the shape $4k+3$. We show that the congruence $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution.

Note  that $a^{p-1}=(a^2)^{(p-1)/2}$, and that $(p-1)/2$ is odd. Since $a^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, it follows that $a^{p-1}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, which contradicts Fermat's Theorem.

For non-primes of the form $4k+3$, it is enough to show that $4k+3$ always has a prime divisor of the shape $4l+3$, and then we can use the previous result.

For $a^2+6^2$, we can certainly get divisibility by $3$. But if $p$ is of the form $4k+3$, and $p\gt 3$, then $p$ cannot divide $a^2+6^2$. We give only a hint for the proof. Suppose that $a^2+6^2\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Multiply through by $c^2$, where $c$ is an inverse of $6$ modulo $p$, that is, $ac\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Thanks very much, never saw anything like this proof, they avoid it in solutions in every book i've read, they just say it's impossible, and when i multiply by c if p>=7 then (6,p)=1 so there exists unique inverse, and then i get k^2=-1(mod p) which we proved is impossible.If i change 6 to b, this will stand for p>b in the same way?

Comment: You are welcome. I think a proof that if $p$ has shape $4k+3$, then $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ has no solution can be found in most introductory books in number theory. There is a structurally similar group-theoretic proof.

Comment: Am i right about changing 6 to b?that 4k+3=p|a^2+b^2 => p|b =>p|a because if (p,b)=1 inverse exists and i do what u hinted me so that is impossible?

Comment: Let $p$ be of shape $4k+3$. If $p$ is not $3$, the inverse of $6$ modulo $p$ exists, say it is $c$. From $a^2\equiv -(6^2)\pmod{p}$ we get $(ac)^2\equiv -(6c)^2 \equiv -1\pmod{p}$. But by our first calculation, this last congruence has no solution. That is, we cannot have $(ac)^2\equiv -1$.